# Unresolved Linking Dependencies in C

Tags: c, dll, linker, static-linking, cl.exe

I've a directory named Proj1, which contains sub-directories, .C and .h files. There is another directory named Proj2, which again has sub-directories, .C and .h files. However, these .C files in Proj2 need to call functions, use Constants, etc. mentioned in the files in Proj1.

After that, I plan to compile Proj2 files to Proj2.dll.

I'm getting Linking errors LNK2019 - Unresolved external symbol, when I try to do the compilation. I'm using Visual Studio cl command to do the same.  The command I'm using is:
`cl /I"E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\include" /I"E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\include\win32" /I"E:\Proj1\bin\include" /MD /LD MainFile.c /FeProj.dll`
Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: kindly paste linker command

Comment: ... show the error messages.

Comment: @theadnangondal Please find below the command. This command is run from the Proj2 directory. `cl /I"E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\include" /I"E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\include\win32" /I"E:\Proj1\bin\include" /
MD /LD MainFile.c /FeProj.dll`

Comment: just to _prepend_ @theadnangondal `Please edit your question and...` :-)

Comment: @MichaelWalz LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol. I'm getting more than 45 such errors, all LNK2019.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'm sorry if any part of this post is ambiguous. Can you please let me know which part needs editing ?

Comment: What i meant is to [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27897634/edit) your original question and post the error message there, instead of putting it in a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897634/unresolved-linking-dependencies-in-c?noredirect=1#comment44195791_27897634).

Comment: I see now lib-dir switches. Plenty of include-dir switches, so you at least compile. I'd say you need to (a) add the library paths where you additional required libs with the missing symbols are located, and (b) add those libs, *both* to the cmd line being executed.

Comment: @WhozCraig The option `/I"E:\Proj1\bin\include"` specifies the path where the .C, .h files are located. I tried compiling the Proj1 files separately to .lib files, but I don't know how to use static libraries in this scenario.